# Cursor in tinymce in ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce

The textarea to which I apply tinymce has id: testTiny.

I have this event:

```
ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
                $($('#testTiny_ifr').contents()).find('body#tinymce')[0].innerText = $($('#testTiny_ifr').contents()).find('body#tinymce')[0].innerText.replace('something', '');
                ed.updatedSelectionBookmark = ed.selection.getBookmark(1);
            }
});
```

But my cursor always goes to the beginning of the textarea. This is very annoying. Is there a way to resolve it?

I tried with:

```
ed.selection.select(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder_ie')[0]);
ed.dom.remove(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder_ie')[0]);
```

and the cursor visually is set, but when I start typing nothing happens. I need to click on the cursor and then my letters will start showing after typing.